# Is it possible to configure a jmsTemplate Topic publisher and also a Queue message producer in the same springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, jms-topic, jmstemplate, jms-queue

My application is using a Queue Originally, So I need to also Implement a Topic for the same application. I'm having difficulties setting up the configurations. please help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define two JmsTemplate beans

```
    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        template.setPubSubDomain(false);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplatePubSub(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        template.setPubSubDomain(true);
        return template;
    }
```

This will prevent Boot from declaring its own template

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked. to be sure I gave the Bean names.